# xhtml required contact form fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml, contact-form

I have HTML form fields on a contact page which then send the data to a php page.

I would like to make the form fields required and show a red (*) next to the label if the user does not enter a value.

How can I do this?

```
<form id="contact_form" method="post" action="contact.php">

    <p style="margin-top:20px">
        <label for="title">Title</label><br/>
        <input id="your_name" name="your_name" type="text" style="width:94%"/>
    </p>

    <p style="margin-top:20px">
        <label for="initial">Initial</label><br/>
        <input id="initial" name="initial" type="text" style="width:94%"/>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-top:20px">
        <label for="surname">Surname</label><br/>
        <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" style="width:94%"/>
    </p>
        <p style="margin-top:20px">
        <label for="tel_number">Tel number</label><br/>
        <input id="tel_number" name="tel_number" type="text" style="width:94%"/>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-top:20px">
        <label for="email">Email</label><br/>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" style="width:94%"/>
    </p>

    <p style="margin-top:20px">
        <label for="enquiry">Enquiry</label><br/>
        <textarea id="enquiry" name="enquiry" rows="7" cols="10" style="width:94%"></textarea>
    </p>

    <p style="margin-top:50px">
        <input type="submit" value="Send Message"/><br/>
    </p>

</form>
```

Comment: You've tagged this jQuery. Have you tried a jQuery-based validation library?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put the form in a php file (or `.phtml` recommended*). Add a css class like `.input-error`.

```
.input-error { color: red; }
```

In your form you'll need something like this for each field:

```
if (empty($postData['field']) {
    echo "<span class=\"input-error\">*</span>";
}
```

To give a clear-cut example:

```
<p style="margin-top:20px">
    <?php if (empty($postData['your_name']): ?>
        <span class="input-error">*</span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <label for="title">Title</label><br/>
    <input id="your_name" name="your_name" type="text" style="width:94%"/>
</p>
```

The form will have to submit to a php file that will process the form and bring you back to this page.  In that file you'd need a line like this:

```
$postData = $_POST;
```

Or, if that script redirects to another page then you'll need to store the post data in the session. like:

```
$_SESSION['postData'] = $_POST;
```

In which case, at the top of your form or somewhere in the controller (if there is one), retrieve that data like so:

```
$postData = $_SESSION['postData'];
```